# Can meta tags replace structured data for Google News articles?

Tags: meta-tags, structured-data, google-news

I've a news website included in Google News. I've used to use [`hEntry`](http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry) schema to give my news articles the structured data of articles.

Now I want to remove my structured data tags/attributes and rely on the meta tags only.

For example, instead of the structured data for date:

```html
<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2017-07-20T04:40:19+00:00"></time>
```

I want to rely on this meta tag:

```html
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-07-20T04:40:19+00:00" />
```

Are they the same for Google bot?

Comment: If you need to have meta tags for some reason, you could keep the structured data markup as well.  It isn't visible to users, so there isn't much harm in keeping it.

Comment: This meta tag is also structured data: the `property` attribute is defined by RDFa. A plain HTML meta tag uses `name`, not `property`. -- So your question seems to be: *Can I use RDFa instead of Microformats for Google News?* -- Anyway, did you check the documentation for Google News? I’d expect it to state which metadata it recognizes.